# Discrete Structures : predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Can anyone help me understand why this might be wrong?

You can’t fool all of the people all of the time.

(∀x) [P(x) /\ (∀y)(T(y)-> ~ F(x,y))]

Answer (score 1):

You have: $\forall x \Bigg(P(x) \wedge \forall y\; \Big(T(y) \to \neg F(x,y)\Big)\Bigg)$

Which says: "All $x$ are people *and* for any $y$ that is a time then you can't fool that person at that time."

Basically: "*Everything* is a person that cannot be fooled at any time."

---

You want: $\forall x \Bigg(P(x) \to \neg \forall y\;\Big(T(y) \to F(x,y)\Big)\Bigg)$

"For any $x$ if it is a person then not any $y$ if that is a time then you can fool that person at that time"

Or equivalently: $\forall x \Bigg(P(x) \to \exists y\;\Big(T(y) \wedge \neg F(x,y)\Big)\Bigg)$

"For any $x$ that is a person then there is a $y$ that is a time and you cannot fool that person at that time."

Or even: $\exists x \Bigg(P(x)\wedge \exists y \Big(T(y) \wedge \neg F(x,y)\Big)\Bigg)$

"There is $x$ that is a person and $y$ that is a time and you cannot fool that person at that time."

Which all mean: "You cannot fool all the people all the time"

$$\neg \Bigg(\forall x \Big(P(x) \to \forall y \big(T(y) \to F(x,y)\big)\Big)\Bigg)$$

---

**Keynotes:**

To state "for *every* thing in a category there is a happening" use $\forall x (C(x)\to H(x))$

To state "for *some* thing in a category there is a happening" use $\exists x (C(x)\wedge H(x))$

Then the statement "*Not* for every thing in a category there is a happening" becomes "for some thing in a category there is a not-happening"

$$\neg\forall x(C(x)\to H(x)) \equiv \exists x (C(x) \wedge \neg H(x))$$

Comment: oooooooooooooooooooooooooo, thanks =-D it makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: Wait - that is not equivalent. Suppose there is a person who is always fooled (i.e., exists x such that P(x) and for all y, T(y) and F(x,y). That is to say more colloquially, you can fool some of the people all of the time. You forbid this possibility; you assert that for each person, it is not the case they can always be fooled.

Comment: @AngelGonzalez: Note that there are multiple interpretations of the English sentence: (1) No matter at what time, you can't fool anyone at all. (2) No matter at what time, there is always someone you can't fool. (3) There is some time at which you can't fool someone. (4) There is some time at which you can't fool everyone.

Comment: That there is, which is both cool and a pain in the butt lol =D

Answer (score 1):

A counter-example to "you CAN fool ALL of the people ALL of the time" would need to be of the form: there exists both a person x, and a time y, such that person x is not fooled at time y:

$$\exists x (\exists y ((P(x) \wedge T(y) \wedge \neg F(x,y)))$$

Of course, as Lincoln also asserted (which need not contradict the above):

$$\exists x (\forall y ((P(x) \wedge T(y)) \rightarrow F(x,y)))$$

"there exists a person who can be fooled for all times". And

$$\exists y (\forall x ((P(x) \wedge T(y) \rightarrow F(x,y)))$$

"there exists a time for which all persons are fooled". But as in your question, he finally asserts:

$$\neg(\forall x (\forall y ((P(x) \wedge (T(y)) \rightarrow F(x,y)))$$

which is equivalent to the asserting that the above counter-example is true.

Comment: thanks =-D, reading the examples with explainations helped me understand predicate logic a lot better. (online classes take away from the in class hands on practice)

Comment: It is a good place to ask questions!